# SSIS 2012 - Error output columnname

Tags: sql, error-handling, ssis

We are building a SSIS package for a customer where a lot of conversion checks happen in 1 dataflow task. We output any errors to a script that generates a new record for our Error-table. That error-table could then be consulted to check if any errors occurred.

We are aware that there are a few scripts and components out there to retrieve the real columnname from an error-output. But those are all for 2008 R2 or lower.

Secondly, we compared our 2012 xml with the 2008 R2, 2008 xml and there isn't any sign anymore of a lineageID, so we think that the scripts and components above will not function anymore.

Weird thing is though that in our designer in the advanced edit screen, we can see our lineageId's. Sadly, we fear that those are generated on runtime and can be different every run. So we can't script against those to retrieve the real columnname.

Anybody has any tips or tricks to resolve this?

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: So, your script (that handles the errors) doesnt output the ColumnID?

Comment: It outputs the errorcode and columname, but columnname is the lineageId. And as we tested by now. Those are generated on runtime. This leads to not have any ability to retrieve the true columnname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Benny Austin's solution](http://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/ssis-name-of-errorcolumn/)

This provided me with an answer. Do read the comments about the package though, you might need to fiddle somethings before it works. But eventually it does.

Comment: How well would this work for multiple packages given that column ID's could very well overlap. Do you create new tables for lookup?

Comment: You get a package ID and PackageName in those tables. So you could easily query the needed package in your dataflows.

Comment: Ah right. I completely forgot about PackageID. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: KyorCode, can you please rebuild a working sln from the source code and share it with us? I removed all references and re-added them...but still doesn't work. console window pops open and closes immediately when I debug the app...did you do anything else?

Comment: I has been a while since I used this code. The problem is that it is owned by a customer and I don't have any rights to share it.